# jQuery plugin methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new to jQuery plugin creation and created a plugin for my project [Tumblr style tagging].

[I know there are so many plugins available but i want to create myself :D]

here it goes

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.Tagger = function () 
    {
        this.each(function()

        {
                //codes goes here

        });

    };


})(jQuery);
```

so that after doing this i can do something like this to create taggable input

```
$("#IdOfTheElement").Tagger();
```

Now i created the UI and need to get the value of the UI.

For example user types `meta` as `google` , `yahoo` ,`msn`  ....

so that i need to get the values as `google,yahoo,msn` .

i want to know the method of doing this [not the code]

something like this available ?

```
$("#ID").Tagger("value"); //returns the values
```

or

```
$("#ID").Tagger().val(); // is this possible ?
```

Hope you understand the question ,all comments/suggestions are welcome.

Please help me complete.

Thank you.

**Update**

Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pNqUL/

Comment: i suggest you read more about [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). it's pretty much explained here how to do what you are doing. Also, use a [boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/) so that you won't be scratchcoding all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last on you specified is possible by changing the code to this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.Tagger = function () 
    {
        return this.each(function()

        {
                //codes goes here

        });

    };


})(jQuery);
```

by returning the orignal selector match you are able to continue the daisy chain of commands. so if `$('#ID')` was a form field, then `$("#ID").Tagger().val();` would return the value

Comment: Thanks for that ,i got the idea about the `chainability `,but i cannot do this by just returning the selector ,because the taggable input is not actually a input of type text [or some element that can return the value] it is a combination of `ul` and `li` ,is there any other way ?

Comment: I can't tell what this script is trying to accomplish. Can you condense it to something more or less in this format: http://jsfiddle.net/nathanjosiah/aCP7X/

Comment: You are in the right way ,returning the values means that getting all the text values of all `li`  elements inside the `ul`

Comment: You are providing the code ,not a method to do this,i am trying to get some ideas about Plugin Methods.

Comment: I apologize, your question is very vague and it appears you were just looking for code to solve the problem.

Comment: Pardon me ,my language is very poor and it killing me in SO,but hopes that i clearly said about this on the question ,u can see that i mentioned it as `i want to know the method of doing this [not the code]` ..no probs...actually i can done this by creating two namespaces ,but i wnt to do this inside the Tagger namespace,thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I collected all of my plugin's methods in an object literal and called them by passing the string name of the method to the plugin [as per the tutorial says...].

so to apply the tagger i can do

```
$("#ID").tagger(); // making element as taggable

$("#ID").tagger("value") //returns the value of tagged elements
```